# Proving the $0/0$ Case of L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise I have been working on today from Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*:

> **Exercise 5.3.11. Use the Generalized Mean Value Theorem to furnish a proof of the $0/0$ case of L'Hospital's rule (Theorem 5.3.6.).**

Recall the $0/0$ case of L'Hospital's rule:

> **Theorem 5.3.6. (L'Hospital's rule: $0/0$ case).** Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions defined on an interval containing $a$, and assume that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on this interval, with the possible exception of the point $a$. If $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$, then
>   $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L\Longrightarrow\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L.$$

Also recall the Generalized Mean Value Theorem:

> **Theorem 5.3.5. (Generalized Mean Value Theorem).** If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, then there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ where
>   $$[f(b)-f(a)]g'(c)=[g(b)-g(a)]f'(c).$$
>   If $g'$ is never zero on $(a,b)$, then the conclusion can be stated as
>   $$\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}.$$

First of all, I am a little confused about the theorem's statement: is it asking me to assume that *both* $f(a)=g(a)=0$ *and* $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)/g'(x)=L$ to show that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/g(x)=L$? If so, can I introduce a subinterval $(a,b_1)$ such that
$$\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}=\frac{f(b_1)-f(a)}{g(b_1)-g(a)}=\frac{f(b_1)}{g(b_1)}?$$
I am not sure, since the theorem states that $f$ and $g$ may not necessarily be differentiable at $a$. Nevertheless, I have the feeling that I could be close if it were not for my shortsightedness. -_-

But anyway, what do you guys think? And thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes the theorem asks you to assume that $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and the limit of the ratio of the derivatives as $x \to a$ is $L$ is also known. You are to prove that the ratio of functions as $x \to a$ also approaches $L$. Which theorem tells you $f$ and $g$ may not be differentiable at $a$?

Comment: @Kannappan: No, it explicitly says "with the possible exception of the point $a$".

Comment: @Josué: There seems to be something missing in the statement of L'Hôpital's rule, an assumption about the denominators not being $0$ away from $a$; else those expressions aren't defined.

Comment: @joriki I am sorry as I did not see that! And, that is also standard to assume in L'Hospital rule. I am deleting that comment!